# Under what circumstances the firestore's onFailureListener will trigger

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I am making an app which uses firestore in am using `onSuccessListener` just to know if task was successful and then show a toast message , and `onFailtureListener` just to know if it was unsuccessful and then show toast for that , but can i remove those listeners and assume that data will be written always and fetched always if i know the references will always be valid.

Or in other words in what situations my `onFailureListener` will trigger.

I am facing one more problem , because of offline support the new data immediately shows up in UI even if the user is offline which is good **but** the `onSuccessListener` only triggers when user get back online,
showing data in UI should mean that the task was successful and `onSuccessListener` should be triggered online.

Isn't it wired the user sees the data in UI and thinks it was added successfully and after a minute when he gets back online he sees a toast  saying data was added , and now he thinking which data?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assume that any write will eventually succeed.  The most common cases for Firestore write failures are violations of security rules, and exceeding some limit (such as individual write limits for a document).

You can see a list of all the possible errors in the API documentation for [FirebaseFirestoreException.Code](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FirebaseFirestoreException.Code).

Comment: ok sir, thanks , may you please also address the second part of the question

Comment: It's not weird. It's a feature that makes your app seem appear very responsive, and also usable while offline.  If you design your app correctly, you writes should almost never fail anyway.

Comment: hmmm that means i should not show the toast message in onSucceslistner otherwise it will appear when the user get back online, then where do i show the toast , if i show toast right away, after the call to set() method the what  if the write fails, and  because the data is shown in UI  right away and if the writes fails then what happens will the data disappear from UI

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it separately. On  Stack Overflow the limit is one question per post.